# Best api for getting an absolute Path object in java (Paths.get("foo", "bar") returns a relative path)

Tags: java

I want to copy a file from an absolute location to another absolute location using `Files.copy(srcPath, dstPath)`. I was attempting to do this with something like the following:

```
Files.copy(Paths.get("first", "path"), Paths.get("second", "path"))
```

However, I received an error because `first/path` does not exist (i.e., it's looking for the relative path). I can think of some ways of getting around this, but they all seem a little hacky given the existence of the simple `Paths` api (e.g., getting the path from a file , copying using file streams, etc.), but I'm hoping that the addition of `Paths` to java 7 is accompanied by a nice api call to create an absolute path. Is there such a method to easily create an absolute path in the standard java 7 libraries?

Comment: Lots of methods on Path that may help depending on how you want to resolve the path http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html

Comment: If the relative `first/path` does not exist, expressing that same location using an absolute path won't help since it still wouldn't exist. Please clarify.